# How would the reference angle (or triangle) look like in the case of $Sin 210^\circ$ in quadrant $3$ of the unit circle?

Tags: trigonometry

I was into a trig book for a while and something clicked me which I do not understand so I am asking it here.

Suppose I need to find the value  $Sin 120^\circ$, I know then, I have to take a reference angle (or triangle) in quadrant 2 as shown below.

[image]

But, how would the reference angle of $Sin210^\circ$ look like? In which quadrant would it fall? I have listed **2** approaches below. Help me track down the correct one.

**Approach 1** This?

[image]

Or **Approach 2**?

[image]

Look, in $Sin 120^\circ$, we subtract $60^\circ$ from $180^\circ$ (as $180^\circ$ is the bigger angle here) and proceed on to find out the values of $Sin 60^\circ$ as it is the reference angle there.

Then, Shouldn't **Approach 2** be correct as there I am subtracting $60^\circ$ from $270^\circ$ (as $270^\circ$ is the bigger angle here) and make the reference angle on $Y-Axis$?

Also please, be kind enough to enlighten me with the reasons as to why one of the **2** approaches is correct.

Thank You. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach number $1$ is correct. The reference angle should always be between your ray of interest and the $x$-axis. The reference angle for $210^\circ$ is $210^\circ-180^\circ=30^\circ$. This is because the cosine and sine of $210^\circ$ are the same as the cosine and sine of $30^\circ$, except for both of them being negative.

Reference angles aren't relative to an angle that's necessarily bigger or smaller in every case. In the first quadrant, the reference angle of $\theta$ is $\theta-0^\circ$. In the second quadrant, it's $180^\circ-\theta$. In the third quadrant, it's $\theta-180^\circ$. In the fourth quadrant, it's $360^\circ-\theta$.

Comment: Is reference angle always made on $X-Axis$?

Comment: Yes, it's always the angle to the nearest part of the $x$-axis.

Comment: Is it always necessary for us to take a reference angle for angles whose sin we have to find for greater than $90^\circ$?

Comment: Personally, I never do it. I just picture the unit circle. I guess maybe I’m implicitly thinking of one...

Comment: I think there is no specific use of reference angles. The thing is that we need to find the coordinates of the point on which terminal ray of the angle intersects the unit circle and for that we have introduced the term $reference angles$ which almost always turn out to be $0^\circ, 30^\circ,45^\circ,60^\circ$. These reference angles give us nice coordinates (whole numbers) which angles like $210^\circ$ or angles greater than $90^\circ$ do not. So that is why we use reference  angles. Right sir?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. The idea is that we only need to learn coordinates for first-quadrant angles, and then note how every other angle “looks like” something in the first quadrant. We measure them from the $x$-axis so we’re only ever dealing with sign changes, and not swapping $x$ and $y$.

Comment: We can get the same information by writing down identities instead such as: $\sin (180^\circ - x) = \sin x$, $\sin (180^\circ + x)=-\sin x$...